# Remove 1 character in the last value of a column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 1 column, how do I remove a character from the last value in the column, for example:

```
'1234',
'4567',
'45SD',
'65SD',
'7Q98',
'Q8E7',
```

The last value is 'Q8E7', and I want to remove "," so result would be:

```
'1234',
'4567',
'45SD',
'65SD',
'7Q98',
'Q8E7'
```

(note the missing `,` after `'Q8E7'`)

This is something I need to do on a daily basis, and the number of records in the column will never be the same.

Thanks.

Comment: it would be helpful to provide sample data as @Georgery suggested

Comment: And what have you tried? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I don’t see the difference between your example and the result you expect. They are both the same

Comment: Sample data is: df = c("'1234',", "'4567',", "'45SD',", "'65SD',", "'7Q98',", "'Q8E7',")

It executes, but is not replacing the "," in the column

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
x=c('1234', '4567', '45SD', '65SD', '7Q98', 'Q8E7,')
gsub(",","",tail(x,1))
```

EDIT:

`c(head(df,-1),sub(",","",tail(df,1)))`

Comment: Code executes, but is not replacing the "," in the column

Comment: why would you load the `stringr` library?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
substr(df[nrow(df),1], 1, nchar(x) - 1)
```

Comment: `df`is the dataframe here. (You didn't provide sample data.)

Comment: When I run it, it returns "character(0)" in the console, but is not replacing it in the DF

Comment: Sample data is:
df = c("'1234',", "'4567',", "'45SD',", "'65SD',", "'7Q98',", "'Q8E7',")

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some explanation.

Comment: I run it, and in the console I get this message "character(0)", but in the dataframe no change is made on the last record.